# Show Date field only if its between other 2 date fields

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

Say I have 3 date columns:

- Action_Date,
- Application_date
- Signed_Date

```
SELECT ACTION_DATE, APPLICATION_DATE, SIGNED_DATE
FROM S.Ser
```

Wanted condition: show `Signed_date` only if it's between `Action_date` and `Application_Date`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `where` clause:

```
SELECT SIGNED_DATE
FROM S.Ser
WHERE SIGNED_DATE BETWEEN Action_date and Application_Date;
```